# How do I remove the green and purple fringing from the B&W blouse in this photo?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, chromatic-aberration, lens-correction

[image]

How can I remove green and purple colors from this photo? In Lightroom, I tried the 'Remove Chromatic Aberration' option but it doesn't help.

Comment: Not all of the color may be there due to CA. Some of it may be reflected light. And some of it could be color moire.

Comment: Lightroom defringe works really well, if you have LR.

Comment: Is it possible that the sliders for chromatic aberration in Lightroom where at 0. If so the "Remove Chromatic Aberration" won't do anything. You may need to move the sliders up a bit to see the effect.

Answer (score 5):

Since the cloth is white, and the other colour is black, you could simply desaturate( remove all saturation) at whole region of cloth. I've done the same multiple times

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Thanks for answer. The problem was that I shot 100 pictures :/